# Is there an objective-c git library that would support push/pull against a remote repository?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, git, macos

Is there an objective-c git library that would support pushing to/pulling from a remote repository? I'm familiar with [objective-git](http://github.com/schacon/objective-git), but if I'm reading it correctly, it is for interaction with a local repository.

Ideally, the library would work on iOS and Mac OS X, and would be permissible for inclusion in app store apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Git.framework: https://github.com/geoffgarside/Git.framework

It doesn't have remote support yet, but it's on the planned feature list, so at least add it to your watch list.

Answer (score 9):

How about **this** [objective-git](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git#readme)? Led by [@Tim Clem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7869/tim-clem), it's the "official" libgit2 binding for Objective-C (It's also been used by GitHub to build their [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) desktop client app).

carlosmn, as part of a [GsoC project](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/google/gsoc2011/carlosmn/13001), is currently [implementing](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/300) networking features in libgit2.

Once it's done, Push/Pull will be exposed by objective-git.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) -- it is a linkable c library that could probably work for you.